Нужно ли тире после "которого"?
Я участвую в проекте, главная цель которого — проанализировать перспективы развития.

• Правило

§ 12. Тире ставится при выражении и подлежащего, и сказуемого (или только подлежащего, или только сказуемого) инфинитивом: В этом городе знать три языка — ненужная роскошь (Ч.); Hu с чем не сравнимое чувство — слышать их [грачей] в первый раз после шестимесячной зимней смерти! (Бун.)...

• Примеры из Нацкорпуса
Так назвали работники парка оригинальный пешеходный маршрут, главная цель которого — возбудить у человека радостные эмоции, вызвать хорошее настроение (Марат Шишигин. Волшебники из Друскининкай // «Огонек». № 11, 1970).
Уничтожение Берии было первым дворцовым переворотом, цель которого — окончательно отмежеваться от методов сталинской карательной политики... (Давид Самойлов. Общий дневник).
— Да нет, это просто очередной рекламный трюк, цель которого — привлечь как можно больше туристов в эти прекрасные края (В. Дмитриев. Несси отмечает свое столетие // «Техника - молодежи», 1975).
✦ Вывод
Я бы поставила тире:
Я участвую в проекте, главная цель которого — проанализировать перспективы развития.
Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым (ПАС)
